# Matrix with .... in latex?

Tags: amsmath, matrices

How to have a matrix draw like this?

[image]

```
\begin{bmatrix}
m_{11} & m_{12} & ... & M_{1c}\\
m_{21} & m_{22} & ... & M_{2c}\\
m_{l1} & m_{l2} & ... & M_{lc}
\end{bmatrix}
```

Below is my output:
[image]

Comment: You are actually just looking for the appropriate symbol - `\vdots` in this case. Also, you need `\ldots` or `\cdots` (depending on preference) for the horizontal dots.

Comment: Just fleshing out @Werner's comment and adding `\ddots` to the story: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{bmatrix}
m_{11} & m_{12} & \cdots & m_{1c}\\
m_{21} & m_{22} & \cdots & m_{2c}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
m_{l1} & m_{l2} & \cdots & m_{lc}
\end{bmatrix}\]
\end{document}`. For fancier realizations, you may want to look at the `nicematrix` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(posting this so that the query may be considered to have received a complete answer.)

I suggest using `\vdots` and `\ddots` in the third row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' env.
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional (Times Roman font)
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{A}_{l\times c}=
\begin{bmatrix}
m_{11} & m_{12} & \dots  & m_{1c} \\
m_{21} & m_{22} & \dots  & m_{2c} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
m_{l1} & m_{l2} & \dots  & m_{lc}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```